# Need help understanding Promise.all and async

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

This is the code I'm going to be talking about.

```
view: async (req, res, next) => {  
        let formato = req.query.formato || 'details';
        try {
            let mode = Client.getMode(formato);

            let options = {
                columns: mode.columns,
                withRelated: mode.withRelated,
            };
            let client_promises = [ ]

            req.query['ids'].map( id => {

                let client =  Client.findById(id, options);
                client_promises.push(client)

            })

            let response = await Promise.all(cliente_promesas)

            return res.json({ success: true, data: response });
        } catch (error) {
            return next(error);
        }
    },
```

I understand that the `.map`  function iterates over an array of ids, which then is passed to `Client.findById`  so it can return a promise to be fulfilled, getting the client's data when it resolves.

Now, those promises are pushed to an array, which then is passed to `Promise.all`, but I dont really understand **where** they are being resolved. Isnt `Promise.all` just passing a resolved promise when all promises in the array are resolved?

I also understand that `await` just makes the code wait for the resolution of the promise before continuing.
But where are the promises in `client_promises`  being resolved?
I know this is basic but for the life of me I cant seem to read enough manuals and guides to be able to understand this.

Comment: Likely `Client.findById` resolves the promise.

Comment: `Promise.all([ promise1, promise2, promise3 ])` will automatically launch all three promises, wait for them all to be resolved (whatever their order), then send back a "ok done" signal which you are `await`ing. But it looks like you already understood this, so I'm not sure where you're stuck?

Comment: @JeremyThille So ``` Promise.all ```  executes the promises? I understood that it just waits for them to be resolved (by another fragment of the code). Does ``` Promise.all ```  also executes them, and sends a resolved promise if they are resolved? Thank you

Comment: Yes, that's how I understand the thing

Comment: @zero298 My confussion stems from the fact that console.log( client ) shows me
```{ isFulfilled: false,
  isRejected: false,
  fulfillmentValue: undefined,
  rejectionReason: undefined }```

Comment: @JeremyThille No, `Promise.all` doesn't "fire" the promises.  They are already "hot" by the time they get to the `Promise.all` and could even be resolved by then.

Comment: @JeremyThille What do you mean they are already hot?

Comment: I wasn't the one to say that, but I'm also interested by the answer

Comment: Oh, sorry. Linking the user that really posted that now @zero298

Answer (score 2):

All `Promise.all` does is wait for every Promise in the array passed to it to be done.  It doesn't "fire" them.  In fact every Promise in the array passed might even be in a resolved state.  The Promises are "hot" from the moment they are created.

For your example, the function to get an item by id starts immediately and **synchronously** returns a Promise that will eventually resolve to whatever object is retrieved by id.  This is key: the returning of the Promise is **not** the asynchronous part, it's the resolution.

`Promise.all` makes all the promises one **big** promise.

Consider the example below.  I take 3 ids and do exactly what you do, I call `findById` and put what is returned by the function (a Promise) into an array, `promises`.  In the `findById`, I also add an *extra* `.then` call to demonstrate how these Promises are "hot" and not waiting to be called by `Promise.all`.  Also note that I still return the `p`.

By the time we actually get to the `Promise.all`, all of the Promises in `promises` have actually resolved, that's why you see them print to console first.  They all take 100-600 milliseconds to resolve, but we actively wait a full 1000 milliseconds before we call `Promise.all`.

Unfortunately (kind of) there is no API to reveal the state of a Promise using the native implementation.  I think there used to be ways with user land libraries like Bluebird and jQuery, but not with how the browser does it.  Otherwise, we could inspect the Promise right before calling the `Promise.all` and see whether they were resolved or pending.

```js
/**
 * Utility function to wait a duration before resolving
 * @param {number} [delay=100] How long to wait
 * @returns {Promise<undfined>} Promise that will resolve after delay
 */
function timeout(delay = 100) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, delay);
  });
}

/**
 * Simulated find function that returns an object
 * @param {number} id The id of the object to get
 * @returns {Promise<object>} The fake DB object
 */
async function findById(id) {
  await timeout((Math.random() * 500) + 100);
  return {
    id,
    data: `foo-${id}`
  };
}

(async function() {
  const idsToGet = [1, 2, 3];
  const promises = idsToGet.map(id => {
    // Call to get the object
    const p = findById(id);

    // Let's add another listener here to know when they are done
    p.then(r => {
      console.log(`${r.id} is done`);
    });

    // Still return the actual Promise created by findById
    return p;
  });

  // Just for kicks
  await timeout(1000);

  // Wait for EVERYTHING to be done
  const res = await Promise.all(promises);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
}());
```

Comment: So when you say **This is key: the returning of the Promise is not the asynchronous part, it's the resolution.**, is that the reason why when I try to console log ```client``` after ```client = Cliente.findById( ... )``` I get an unresolved promise? Because the promises didnt resolve yet at the time of logging?
Thank you very much for the time and in-depth response, by the way!.

Comment: @dizzydizzy Yes, in fact that's probably the biggest hurdle to overcome whenever first being introduced to async programming.  `findById` doesn't give you the db entry, it gives you a Promise.  This is made a little bit easier to see/understand/use with `async/await` but it's still something that needs to be understood.

Comment: @dizzydizzy Also, it's not that you tried to console a promise that isn't resolved yet.  Don't try to think in terms of resolved or unresolved Promises, just think in Promises.  Even if the Promise ***was*** resolved by the time you tried to console it, you'd still be consoling a Promise.  You can only reveal the data represented by the Promise through `.then` or with `await`.

Comment: Allright, you gave me quite a bit to think about. **"You can only reveal the data represented by the Promise through .then or with await"** that part, mostly.
I tought that ```.then``` and ```await``` "executed" the promise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Promise.all() takes list/ array of unresolved promises.
It is kind of like a big one **promise** that takes all the unresolved promises and until all of them are resolved the Promise.all() is unresolved.

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = 42;
const promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
```

In the above example, you can see that we are passing 3 promises to Promise.all()
and when all of them are fulfilled then only **.then** will be triggered.

in your case:

```
 Client.findById(id, options);
```

must be returning a promise object which you are pushing into client_promises array.
and then feeding them to Promise.all(), until this point, your promises are just promises they are not resolved.

promise.all also returns a promise and as you have put await in front of it.
it will wait until of them re resolved and give you an array of resolved promises.

Answer (score 0):

The promises are actually *"fired"* (that is, the code starts to run) when you do `let client =  Client.findById(id, options);`. `await Promise.all` then waits until all of them are resolved or one of them is rejected in which case Promise.all also rejects with the value of the first promise rejection.

Comment: Oh, I see. and why do I get ```{ isFulfilled: false, isRejected: false, fulfillmentValue: undefined, rejectionReason: undefined }``` when I'm writing to console ```client```? Is it because the asynchronic nature of the code that they didn't resolve yet, and I only see them resolved when I put an await in front of the ```Promise.all```? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Exactly, if you log `client` (or any other promise) to console you will see the promise (not it's fulfilled value) which at this point is still pending (neither rejected nor fulfilled).